# What should I do if a package has not installation candidates?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt

I am trying to install php5-sqlite3. In the command line I type:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3
```

As I result I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-sqlite3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package php5-sqlite3 has no installation candidate
```

What is happening here and how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want php5-sqlite.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was able to install php5-sqlite and after that I was able to use sqlite from PHP without any additional changes.

Answer (score 3):

You could have found the package you were searching for by using:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search php sqlite
```

More information on the `search` command from the `apt-cache` man page:

> search regex [ regex ... ]
>
> search performs a full text search on all available package lists
>   for the regex pattern given. It searches the package names and
>   the descriptions for an occurrence of the regular expression
>   and prints out the package name and the short description. If --full
>   is given then output identical to show is produced for each
>   matched package, and if --names-only is given then the long
>   description is not searched, only the package name is.
>
> Separate arguments can be used to specify multiple search
>   patterns that are anded together.